# Application blocks in ServerSocket.accept()

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm trying to realize a simple client/server application in Java8.
I'm using this code:

```
`package prova;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;



public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ServerSocket ssock;
        try {
            System.out.println("Listening");
            ssock = new ServerSocket(8080);
            while(true){
                Socket sock;
                try {
                    sock = ssock.accept();
                    System.out.println("Connected");
                    new Thread(new Server(sock)).start();
                }catch(IOException e1){e1.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }catch(IOException e2){e2.printStackTrace();}
    }
}`
```

Server.java

```
package prova;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server implements Runnable{

    Socket clientSocket;

    public Server(Socket cSocket){
        this.clientSocket = cSocket;
    }

    public void run(){
         try {
             PrintStream pstream = new PrintStream
             (clientSocket.getOutputStream());
             for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i--) {
                pstream.println(i + 
                " bottles of beer on the wall");
             }
             pstream.close();
             clientSocket.close();
          }
          catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println(e);
          }
    }

}
```

When the application arrives to execute the instruction ssock.accept();
the application crashes. I really don't know what's the matter with this code. I've searched on internet but except for class server there is no difference between my code and a lot of solution/examples that i found. By the way since the application doesn't arrive to execute the thread I guess this is not related to my issue, maybe I'm wrong.
Thank you all in advance

Comment: If your application "crashes", and you need help, you'll want to tell and show us more, specifically any and all exception stacktraces, and an indication of the lines that throw the exception. Change your catch blocks to read `e.printStacktrace();` for more complete information.

Comment: that's the strange fact it doesn't provide any stacktrace. I'm running this code on win10 with eclipse mars 4.5.2. the code  stops at this instruction  sock = ssock.accept();

Comment: Your application *blocks.*. Not 'crashes'. A crash is a program exit accompanied by a core dump or a debug prompt. `accept()` is a blocking function. There is no problem here to solve.

Answer (score 2):

> that's the strange fact it doesn't provide any stacktrace. I'm running this code on win10 with eclipse mars 4.5.2. the code stops at this instruction sock = ssock.accept();

Yes, it's supposed to stop there -- it's waiting for a client program to connect on that same socket, server socket 8080, that's what `accept()` does, but you don't do that anywhere. The fix is simple -- have your client try to connect on the same socket that the server is waiting on.

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong, sorry for that. I know that the application should stop there and wait for client to connect. But this doesn't happen, I receive from Windows an error with application is not responding.